# removing all white spaces for lines starting with a pattern

Tags: shell, unix, scripting

I need to remove all the white spaces for lines which starting with a pattern in a file.

I don't want to loop through lines. Is there any simple and quick solution?

For example 
Input file:

```
<id xxx>dafd</id>
<r>31,31, 31</r>
<r> 0, 0,0 </r>
```

The output file need to be

```
<id xxx>dafd</id>
<r>31,31,31</r>
<r>0,0,0</r>
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?:

```
echo "<id xxx>dafd</id>
<r>31,31, 31</r>
<r> 0, 0,0 </r>" | sed -r '/<r>/s/ //g;'
<id xxx>dafd</id>
<r>31,31,31</r>
<r>0,0,0</r>
```

Explanation:

- `sed -r` : use extended regular expresions
- `/<r>/` : Lines matching
- `s/ //g;` : Substitute blanks with nothing, globally.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hi you can do it by the below script. First create a file like `mytream.sh` and add below lines and change the permission of the file and execute:-

```
vi mytream.sh
```

now add below lines:-

```
#!/bin/bash

file_to_tream="yourfilename"
sed '/<r>/s/ //g' $file_to_tream > tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt $file_to_tream
```

Or if you do it for any file, just change your script like below and provide the file name in command prompt

```
#!/bin/bash

sed '/<r>/s/ //g' $1 > tmp.txt
mv tmp.txt $1
```

Now run it like

```
chmod 777 mytream.sh
./mytream.sh yourfileName
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. similar with previous solution, however both solved the problem